# How to open update electron browser window with a new html file

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am new to electron. I have two html pages and I want to open the second page when a button clicked. I have code this as follow, but I just get a blank window; not the second page.

This is index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron

app.on('ready',()=>{
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:960, hehight:540})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/login.html`)
})

exports.openWindow = (fileName) => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:960, height:540})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/` + fileName + `.html`)
}
```

This is login.js

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
const index = remote.require('./index.js')

var login = document.getElementById('login')
login.addEventListner('click', () => {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
  index.openWindow('pageTwo')
  window.close()
}, false)
```

login is the id of the html button.

I want to get the page two. How can I perform this?

Comment: do you want the second html file to load in a different browser window ?

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe it is okay to update the current window. I jus want to open the second page and close the first one.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily achieve this by using IPCRenderer and IPCMain in order to pass the messages between the main process and the renderer.

index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = electron

app.on('ready',()=>{
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:960, hehight:540})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/login.html`)
})

ipcMain.on('open-new-window', (event, fileName) => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:960, height:540})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/` + fileName + `.html`)
}
```

As you can see, I altered your code only to add `ipcMain` and receive the message from the renderer.

login.js

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

let login = document.getElementById('login');
login.addEventListner('click', () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'pageTwo');
}, false);
```

The same goes for login.js and `ipcRenderer`.

The documentation explains way better than I do and can be found [here for ipcMain](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) and [here for ipcRenderer](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/).

Answer (score 5):

I have looked at your code and from what I see you are requiring your main process, you can't do this, you need to use [IPC](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) to send a message from your render process or use the remote [BrowserWindow](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) object and get the window from an ID and use loadURL.

Using IPC

index.js

```
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");

ipcMain.on("changeWindow", function(event, arg) {
    switch (arg) {
        case "page1":
            win.loadURL("Page1 URL");
            break;
        case "page2":
            win.loadURL("Page2 URL");
            break;
        case "page3":
            win.loadURL("Page3 URL");
            break;
        ...
    }
});
```

login.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

function onButtonClick() {
    ipcRenderer.send("changeWindow", "page2");
}
```

---

Second option using BrowserWindow remotely.

login.js

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require("electron").remote;

function onButtonClick() {
    let win = BrowserWindow.fromId("ID of your window");

    win.loadURL("URL you want to load (your login.html file)");
}

// OR

function onButtonClick() {
    let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

    win.loadURL("URL you want to load (your login.html file)");
}

// OR

function onButtonClick() {
    /*
        Not the best method but would work.
     */

    let wins = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();

    let windowIndex = /* index of your window in the wins array */

    wins[windowIndex].loadURL("URL you want to load (your login.html file)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

accessing a required functionality with the remote api from the renderer process at times result in a deadlock when ever you call that functionlaity with an argument. You should do this , using `ipc`

```
 // main process
  const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain: ipc } = require("electron");
  let win;
  app.on("ready", () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow();
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
 });

 ipc.on("send-window-id", (event) => {
    event.sender.send("window-id-sent", win.id);
 });


// renderer process

<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <button>new window</button>
      <script>
         const { remote: { BrowserWindow }, ipcRenderer: ipc } = require("electron");

         var button = document.querySelector("button");
         button.addEventListener("click", event => {
           let win = new BrowserWindow();
           win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/page2.html`);
           ipc.send("send-window-id");
        });
        ipc.on("window-id-sent", (event,id) => {
           BrowserWindow.fromId(id).close();
        });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The `BrowserWindow.fromId` recieves the id of a window and returns the window object of that id