# How to redirect to a different Window in ElectronJS without a new Window

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a question on how to redirect to a different page with ElectronJs.

The documentation only covered how to open a new window. But in my case, I do not wish to open a new window. This is what I've been trying so far but it's not responding:

login.js

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn')

loginBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let win = BrowserWindow
    win.on('close', () => { win = null })
    win.loadURL('file:///Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Timetrack/main_page.html')
    win.show()
})
```

The above codes are modified from existing open a new page in a new browser window codes. I tried the following without much success too

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = 'main_page.html'
    })
```

Hoping for someone to assist. I wasn't able to find helpful assistance on StackOverflow so I'm opening this thread, but if someone did indeed has asked this before, I'll be happy to delete this thread too. Just let me know. Thanks.

If you need to see my HTML, here it is:
login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Timetrack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Login-Form-Clean.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(241,247,252);">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: black;">
        <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand app-name" id="app-name" href="#" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;width: 165px;color: white;"><b>Timetrack <sub>by Pyxel Inc</sub></b></a></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="flex-fill login-clean" style="background-size: auto;">
        <form method="post">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-clock"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
            <div id="loginBtn" class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button></div><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an electron.js file to setup the electron window and import in this file an app.js server with express. In this way you can use express for redirect to other page as a web application.
This is the electron.js file

```
const server = require('./app');
var path= require('path')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

var mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/icona-app.png'),
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    useContentSize: true,
    resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      devTools: false
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/');

}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

And this is the app.js file

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Your application is listening on port 8080!')
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/login.html");
})
module.exports=app
```

And then you must edit your package.json file
You must edit this two attributes:

```
"main": "electron.js",
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm install && electron electron.js --no-sandbox"
},
```

To start the application write `npm start`

Comment: Hi @sfale thank you for your input. Does this means that the actual ElectronJS desktop app requires an express server (localhost) in the background? I mean this pretty much defeats the purpose of a desktop app if an express server is required.
Or does Electron compiles the express into it's program too, sort of like a virtual server inside a program powering the miniature chromium browser on Electron?

Comment: Hi @TengBangWei. ElectronJS does not require an express server, it's only an idea for approach to this. For changing page without an express server you need to use IPC to send a message from your render process or use the remote BrowserWindow object and get the window from an ID and use loadURL. I link you a question that explain how to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932154/how-to-open-update-electron-browser-window-with-a-new-html-file

Comment: Fantastic @sfale. Thanks for the help!